# [Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'rowFlag')]

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

[image: I am Getting this as error]

Hello All,

I am in need of your help for the error attached in the pic , How to fix this error .Please help

```
handleSelected(event) {
        const initialState = {Index:'',rowFlag:false,sample1:'',sample2:'',sample3:'',sample4:'',sample5:'',sample6:'',sample7:'',sample8:'',sample9:'',sample10:'',sample11:'',sample12:'',sample13:'',sample14:''};
        var objectname = event.detail.ObjectName;
        var rowthInd = event.detail.rowInd;
        var Listindex = rowthInd.slice(7);
        if( objectname === "Account") {
            this.account = {Name : event.detail.Name, Id: event.detail.Id};
            this.AccList[Listindex].rowFlag  = true;
            //this.AccList[Listindex].Id = this.AccList[Listindex].Id?this.AccList[Listindex].Id:event.detail.Id;
            this.template.querySelector('[Id^="'+rowthInd+'"]').children[2].children[0].children[0].value = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).sample2__c;
            this.AccList[Listindex].sample1 = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).sample1__c;
            this.AccList[Listindex].sample2 = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).sample2__c;
            this.template.querySelector('[Id^="'+rowthInd+'"]').children[3].children[0].children[0].value = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).sample3__c;
            this.AccList[Listindex].sample3= this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).sample3__c;
            this.template.querySelector('[Id^="'+rowthInd+'"]').children[4].children[0].children[0].value =
this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).sample4__c;
            this.AccList[Listindex].sample4 =this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).sample4__c;
            this.template.querySelector('[Id^="'+rowthInd+'"]').children[5].children[0].children[0].value = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).sample5__c;
            this.AccList[Listindex].sample5 = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).sample5__c;
            this.template.querySelector('[Id^="'+rowthInd+'"]').children[6].children[0].children[0].value = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).sample6__c;
            this.AccList[Listindex].sample6 = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).sample6__c;
            this.template.querySelector('[Id^="'+rowthInd+'"]').children[7].children[0].children[0].value = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).sample7__c;
            this.AccList[Listindex].sample7 = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).sample7__c;
            this.template.querySelector('[Id^="'+rowthInd+'"]').children[8].children[0].children[0].value = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).sample8__c;
            this.AccList[Listindex].sample8 = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).sample8__c;
            this.template.querySelector('[Id^="'+rowthInd+'"]').children[9].children[0].children[0].value = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).sample9__c;
            this.AccList[Listindex].sample9 = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).sample9__c;
            if(this.StLt && this.StLt == 'ST'){
                this.template.querySelector('[Id^="'+rowthInd+'"]').children[10].children[0].children[0].value = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).abc1__c;
                this.AccList[Listindex].abc = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).abc1__c;
            }else if(this.StLt && this.StLt == 'LT'){
                this.template.querySelector('[Id^="'+rowthInd+'"]').children[10].children[0].children[0].value = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).xyz1__c;
                this.AccList[Listindex].xyz = this.AccIdAccountRecMap.get(event.detail.Id).xyz1__c;
            }
        }
        event.target.dataset.id =rowthInd ;
        this.handlePropshare(event);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Cannot set properties of undefined means that the object you are trying to set `rowFlag` on is undefined. It is this line:

```
this.AccList[Listindex].rowFlag  = true;
```

This means `this.AccList[Listindex]` is undefined. Check elsewhere in your code as to why that might be the case. Adding some `console.log` lines might help you debug the issue.